# Use line break inside of a for loop in twig using Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

Trying to study the conditional statement. In here I want to indicate if it is even or odd and I want to put some line break after the other.

Example

1 - Odd

2 - Even

Question: Where should I put the |nl2br?

NOTE: I tried this  {{ i ~ " " ~ cycle(['even', 'odd'], i)|nl2br }} and it didnt work.

**My twig**

```
{# For loop even and odd #}

    {% for i in 1..10 %}
    {{ i ~ " " ~ cycle(['even', 'odd'], i) }}

    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget twig is extending HTML - you can just put the HTML you want right in place, as long as it's not inside the `{{ }}`

```
{% for i in 1..10 %}
  {{ i ~ " " ~ cycle(['even', 'odd'], i) }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Though, depending on your purpose, you might want to actually wrap the item in an HTML element:

```
{% for i in 1..10 %}
  <p>{{ i ~ " " ~ cycle(['even', 'odd'], i) }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried this guide. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html. Followed the | YAML but it didnt work on me

Comment: @Angel What has `YAML` to do with your (initial) question?

Comment: As Matteo already answered, |nl2br doesn't add a <br>, it changes any newlines in the string to a <br> - so you could add a "\n" and then convert it using |nl2br, but in this case (putting it at the end of your looped output) it seems much more straightforward and readable to just add the <br> unless you need it in the middle of your looped instances.

Answer (score 1):

The [nl2br](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/nl2br.html):

> The nl2br filter inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a
>   string...

So you should insert a `\n` in your example in order to make the filter works.
You can also use the [odd](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/odd.html) or even [test](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/even.html), as example:

```
{% for i in 1..10 %}
{{ (i ~ " " ~ ( i is odd ? "odd" : "even")~ "\n")|nl2br  }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this help